# How to make an ubuntu 16.04 crash manually?

Tags: 16.04

Just out of curiosity, is it possible to make an Ubuntu 16.04 system crash manually, such that it would look like you would have to reinstall Ubuntu to make it work?

I know that anything we can do can be reverted. I just wanted to know because I didn't find this question anywhere.

Comment: Why would you want to know that?

Comment: @Ziazis Prank.. Perhaps :-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move initrd and vmlinuz.

First create a linux bootable cd or USB (google it)

```
mkdir ~/.lol
find /boot -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec xargs mv {} ~/.lol/
```

Reboot and cry.

To fix you could boot from the linux bootable disk or usb and find the hard disk and move the files back into path/to/sda/boot/*